# Finding the intermediate fields of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $F= \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ with $\zeta_7 = e^{2\pi/7}$.
>
> a) What is the Galois group of $F$ over $\Bbb{Q}$?
>
> b) Find all intermediate fields between $\Bbb{Q}$ and $F$. (Write each in the form $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some specific $\alpha \in F$.)
>
> c) For each intermediate field $E$ above, give the Galois group of $E$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

a) Since $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ is the splitting field for the cyclotomic polynomial $x^6+x^5+\dots+1$, $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/\Bbb{Q}) \cong U_7 \cong \Bbb{Z}^{\times}_7 \cong \Bbb{Z}_6$.

b) $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/\Bbb{Q}) \cong \Bbb{Z}_6$

So we have the following diagram for $\Bbb{Z}_6$,

[image]

And a corresponding diagram for $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$
[image]

Since $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ has complex numbers, we can look at $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ to see if it has degree 2 or 3 over $\Bbb{Q}$. Since $x^2+1$ is its minimal polynomial, we see that $[\Bbb{Q(i)} : \Bbb{Q}]=2$ and so it must correspond to $\Bbb{Z}_3$, and $\beta=i$.

Sending every number to its conjugate is one possible automorphism. Of course, it has order 2 and so is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2$. Since it fixes every real number, the corresponding intermediate field must be of the form $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some real number $\alpha$, and must have degree 3 over $\Bbb{Q}$.

If we look at $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$, we see that

$\cos(2\pi/7) + i\sin(2\pi/7) + cos(12\pi/7) + i\sin(12\pi/7)$

$= \cos(2\pi/7) + i\sin(2\pi/7) + \cos(-2\pi/7) + i\sin(-2\pi/7)$

$= 2\cos(2\pi/7)$

which is irrational. So $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6)$ is either a proper subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ or is equal to it. But from the diagram, we know that there is only one other intermediate field, so $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6) = \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

c) The corresponding Galois group of $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3$ and that of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2$.

Do you think this is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathrm{i}\in F$?

Comment: I agree with @ccorn. Just because $\Bbb Q(i)$ has degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q$ doesn't mean that it's part of your diagram (for example, $\sqrt{2}$ could take the place of $i$.

Comment: tne universe would be immensely more boring if $\mathbb Q(i)$ were the unique quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to assume $\mathrm{i}\in F$, so try another $\beta$. I would suggest
$$\beta = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^4$$
You will easily verify that $\beta+\bar{\beta}=-1$ and $\beta\bar\beta=2$ (thus $\beta$ is irrational) and that $$\mathbb{Q}[X]\ni\operatorname{minpoly}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\beta)=X^2-(\beta+\bar{\beta})X+(\beta\bar{\beta}) = X^2+X+2$$
Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

Edit: Fixed the sloppy notation for $\operatorname{minpoly}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\beta)$. See Gerry Myerson's answer for finding a candidate $\beta$ in general.

Edit 2: $\mathrm{i}\not\in F$ because $\mathrm{i}\zeta_7$ is a primitive $28$th root of unity, so $F(i)$ contains $\zeta_{28}$, whereas $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{28}):\mathbb{Q}] = 12 \neq 6 = [F:\mathbb{Q}]$.

Edit 3: Clarified way to the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have two more questions. I understand that $\beta + \bar{\beta}$ equals $-1$ and $\beta\bar{\beta}=2$. But I'm not sure why you wanted me to verify that. I'm not really sure how this is related to the problem. Also, I'm not sure how you got the minimal polynomial. I tried to simplify $\beta^2 + \beta + 2$ and got $2\zeta_7^3 + 2\zeta_7^5 + 2\zeta_7^6 + 2$...and I can't really see how this can equal zero.

Comment: @Artus: $\beta$ and $\bar{\beta}$ are solutions of $(X-\beta)(X-\bar{\beta}) = 0$, that is, $X^2 - (\beta+\bar{\beta})X + (\beta\bar{\beta}) = 0$. That's how I got the polynomial.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a trick that often works in this kind of problem.

Take an element $\alpha$ of $F$ --- an element that generates $F$ over the ground field.

Take a subgroup $H$ of the Galois group.

Form $\sum_{\sigma{\rm\ in\ }H}\sigma(\alpha)$. This is guaranteed to be invariant under $H$ and thus to live in some subfield. Unless you're unlucky, it generates the fixed field of $H$.

In particular, this is what @ccorn has done in the other answer.

Comment: Please, can you give some references about this result? I think that this works for all cyclotomic fields when p is prime, but I can't find it on books or notes. This seems to me a little strange, since in my opinion this is a pretty useful result.

Comment: @Yecabel, the only result I have stated is that $\beta=\sum_{\sigma{\rm\ in\ }H}\sigma(\alpha)$ is invariant under $H$, and you don't need a reference for that. Just let $\tau$ be in $H$ and apply it to $\beta$. Remember that $\tau$ is an automorphism, so you get the sum, over $\sigma$ in $H$, of $\tau\sigma(\alpha)$; and, as $\sigma$ runs through $H$, so does $\tau\sigma$. This works for any field extension, not just for cyclotomic fields.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to know when it generates the intermediate field!

Comment: @Yec, I don't know any foolproof way to guarantee that. Maybe you should post it as a new question.

Comment: This is equation 14.10 (in section 14.5 cyclotomic extensions and abelian extensions over Q) in Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra book. It's worth noting that this is a general idea from representation theory over finite (or, more generally, compact) groups.