# Find the lattice of intermediate subgroups of a Galois group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Consider the Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/11})$. I am asked to calculate the lattice of the intermediate groups of $G$.

I know that the minimal polynomial of $e^{2\pi i/11}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $m(x)=x^{10}+x^9+ ... + 1$ and therefore $G$ has $10$ elements, and every element moves one root of $m(x)$ to another. The roots of $m(x)$ are the roots of unity $\xi,\xi^2,...\xi^{10}$ where $\xi^{11}=1$

How do I follow?

Comment: Begin with an observation about the order of group $G$.

Comment: I don't know if you mean this: $G$ is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of order $10$ of $S_{10}$. I can calculate by hand the subgroups of, for example $S_3$, but for $S_{10}$ I have no idea.

Comment: I think you are making it too complicated by thinking about  $S_{10}$.  $G$ is only order $10$, so its subgroups are easier to find.

Comment: Ok, therefore all the subgroups must be of order $1,2,5$ or $10$ ($1$ and $10$ are trivial). How do I find these subgroups of order $2$ and $5$?

Comment: Have you got an explicit description of the ten elements in the Galois group?

Comment: Everything can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463968/finding-the-intermediate-fields-of-bbbq-zeta-7) if you replace $p=7$ by $p=11$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde :  It might be worth pointing out that your dup target focuses on identifying intermediate *fields*, while here it is the intermediate *subgroups* which are wanted.  A Galois correspondence is present, but it might be the point of the exercise to realize that correspondence explicitly.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, this is true, but the dupe also has the subgroup lattice of $C_6$, and for $p=11$ we do the lattice for $C_{10}$ here very similarly (both $6$ and $10$ are product of two different primes). So you can just copy the subgroup lattice and relabel it. And if you have a question on Galois theory in the title, it is good anyway to add something more to the group theoretical part.